# Binding in Xamarin ambiguous between the following methods or properties in openCV

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Android Studio app that uses openCV and runs just fine.

It uses a couple of libraries that have been written specifically for the project. They work fine within the project as mentioned.

I am now trying to get this into an .aar and use that in an Xamarin project.

The .aar files have been created and as far as I can tell nothing out of the ordinary there.

I set up a simple Xamarin project to then create a DLL as per various articles one being this ;

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar
```

My problem is when building the dll, I am getting the following error and just cannot understand why nor what it really mean. More particularly it seems it is coming from openCV  ?

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
> 'CameraBridgeViewBase.SetCvCameraViewListener(CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListener)'
> and
> 'CameraBridgeViewBase.SetCvCameraViewListener(CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListener2)'

in

> \verifytest\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.cs

An example of my Android app code which I built the .aar from is as follows ;

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


if (SelfiePage.mFaceDetector.confirmFace(mGray)) {
   MatOfRect roiRegionMat = new MatOfRect();
   SelfiePage.mFaceDetector.getRoi(roiRegionMat);
   org.opencv.core.Rect roiRegion[] = roiRegionMat.toArray();
   if (roiRegion.length > 0) {
      mbHasFace = true;
      org.opencv.core.Rect roi = roiRegion[0];
      mFaceRect.set(1.f * roi.x / mGray.width() * width, 1.f * roi.y / mGray.height() * height, 1.f * (roi.x + roi.width) / mGray.width()
            * width, 1.f * (roi.y + roi.height) / mGray.height() * height);
```

And this is the code (in openCV) (Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.cs) that the VS error is referring to ;

```
public event EventHandler<global::Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CameraViewStartedEventArgs> CameraViewStarted {
    add {
        global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.AddEventHandler<global::Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListener, global::Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListenerImplementor>(
        ref weak_implementor_SetCvCameraViewListener,
        __CreateICvCameraViewListenerImplementor,
        SetCvCameraViewListener,
        __h => __h.OnCameraViewStartedHandler += value);
    }
    remove {
        global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.RemoveEventHandler<global::Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListener, global::Org.Opencv.Android.CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListenerImplementor>(
        ref weak_implementor_SetCvCameraViewListener,
```

I really can't understand what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: try the suggestion in this https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6249

Comment: maybe system can't choose between the 2 overloads